# python pip installation under CentOS 6.4

Tags: python

Will someone please tell me how to install `pip`

My website is not working because modules are missing and the only way I can install them is by installing python's module manager `pip`

`yum install python-pip` fails. How would I install it?

These action should be done via package managers but I wasn't even able to install python 3.4a like that, I had to compile it form source when the easy thing to do was `yum install python3`
what wrong with this `yum` manager?

---

```
======================================================
root@secure [~/distribute-0.6.49]# pip install pygeoip
Downloading/unpacking pygeoip
Downloading pygeoip-0.3.0.tar.gz (97kB): 97kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pygeoip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1098: ordinal not in range(128)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "/usr/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1098: ordinal not in range(128)
======================================================

root@secure [~]# setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8
-bash: setenv: command not found
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yum is a tool that connects to defined remote repositories for
   precompiled software.  It is only going to find software that is
   listed in those repositories.
2. CentOS is a Linux distribution based on RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise
   Linux).  Arguably one of the biggest selling points for RHEL (and by
   extension, CentOS) is that it does NOT try to follow the latest and
   greatest in terms of software packages.  It is designed to be very
   slow moving and stable.  For this reason, you will likely never see
   3.4A in CentOS 6 from the official repositories.  3.4A isn't even beta quality (the A stands for Alpha).
3. There are several yum repositories that supply additional (and often
   updated) packages for CentOS / RHEL.  The most common of these is
   [EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux)](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).  And whaddya know, [python-pip](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/python-pip-1.3.1-4.el6.noarch.rpm) is in there.
4. What's wrong with the yum manager?  Well, that's not a question that can be answered with a short response and would be mostly based on opinions rather than facts.

To help you find information like this in the future, here's how I did it:

I loaded up [Google](http://www.google.com/) in a web browser.  I performed a search for 'CentOS 6 python pip yum', then I followed the first link.